# Tomcat not shutting down in Red Hat 5.5

Tags: redhat, tomcat6

I'm running a Tomcat 6 server on a Red Hat 5.5 machine that I don't have root access for, although I do own all of the Tomcat files.  The server starts up fine when I run `startup.sh`, but for some reason `shutdown.sh` doesn't take down the server.  Do I need to be root to kill my server, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to be root. You also want to see whats going on in catalina.out - the answer to your problem most likely is in that log file.

Comment: root or the same user than the one that is running tomcat...

Comment: Yep, a giant list of exceptions caused by lack of permissions.  I talked to the root user, and it's fixed.  Thanks though, guys.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.mail-archive.com/tomcat-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg105271.html) might help.